# array as function arguments

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm currently recoding some code.
It's from project I'm running at the moment.

```
class store extends TModel{
    public function render_cart( $a=0, $b=0, $c=0 ){
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $a=0, $b=0, $c=0 ); echo '</pre>';
    }
}

class TController extends TObject{
    function getModel($model=''){
        include( TPATH_COMPONENT.'models'.DS.$model.'.php' );
        $this->_model = new $model;
        return false;
    }
    function get($method=''){
        $args = func_get_args();

        return $this->model->$method( $args );
    }
}

$controller->getModel('store');        
$cart = $controller->get('render_cart', 1, 2, 3 );
```

I want transfer args from TController::get to store::render_cart( $a=0, $b=0, $c=0 ) as it's arguments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write the method like this:

```
function get($method=''){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $method = array_shift($args);
    return call_user_func_array([$this->model, $method], $args);
}
```

After getting the method name and arguments into `$args`, use `array_shift` to isolate the method name from the arguments.

To pass the arguments (whose number is unknown) to the model's method you need to use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). You already have the arguments array for this call, but you still need the [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). That one is created on the spot as an array of two items per the documentation.